# WCF Web Services with MySQL, Error in Reading SQL Data?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, json, wcf

I Followed [this](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm) To Create A `WCF Restful Web Services`, which will Display Database As Json So that I can Use this Json in the Part of Android and iOS.

But For the Little Bit Change Instead of `SQL Server` I want to Use **MySQL**.

So I am on process with the Data and Here I added a `Link to SQL` Item and Generated a File `Database1.dbml`
 Here In server Explorer I can Able to see all my tables of a Database But When I Drag and Drop the table I am Getting this error..

**`"The selected object(s) use unsupported data provider."`**

How can I use MySQL data to Create a Restful web service and Display JSON as Output, in .net WCF, I also Tried with MVC from [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api)
But here also Same Problem Reading Database or adding Database.

Any Suggestions please.

Comment: Not an exact dup but give the accepted answer a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571276/the-selected-objects-use-an-unsupported-database-provider

Comment: sorry @rene sir Here when I Use MySQL I am Getting this error on that link they asked for SQL server,...

Comment: Give this a try http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article100.aspx  but I don't expect the drag-and-drop to work...

Answer (score 0):

I got your doubt. So here you can get the correct answer to get the data from MYSQL to our project, follow the link below:

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/articles/tutorial_linq.html

Comment: And may I know the process or a sample project to get Json data of our Database, So that I can Use that Json in the Part of Android and iOS